# Variable name conflicts with function name leads to "Variable used within its own initial value"

Tags: ios, swift, compilation

Having this function

```
private func date(from string: String) {
    // Do thing with string
}
```

when calling it with

```
let date = date(from: "11:30")
```

it produces the following error

`Variable used within its own initial value`

obviously changing the code to

```
let anythingButDate = date(from: "11:30")
```

will make the error go away but I am trying to understand why there is a conflict between variable name and method name in the first place.

**UPDATE**:

To be more precise - I understand that the compiler is having issues with giving the variable and the function the same name but I am curious why can't it distinguish that one is a variable name and the other is a function name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no big distinction between functions and variables because even a variable can hold a function or closure. What you have is a conflict of identifiers.

You can use

```
date = self.date(...)
```

to make the intent clear.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Missed that.

Comment: Considering that it can infer stuff like this in optional binding in guards like `guard someOptional = someOptional else { ... }` this  is pretty stupid that it   can't infer that the right hand side is an application of a function named `date(from:)` that needs to be assigned to a constant called `date` especially since `date(from:)` is not defined anywhere in the current scope so it's not like there's a local scope function/closure variable called `date` that it's getting hung up on.

`date` is a poor example since this should be a convenience constructor on an extension of Date, but still

Comment: @thuggish-nuggets you are wrong. When referencing a method using its name, only its first part is used. That means there actually is a method called `date`. That optional binding is a very specific case because it intentionally shadows a variable.

Comment: Sure but the presence of parenthesis and an argument list indicates the function is to be applied, not treated as a variable. There is no reason the compiler should not be able to infer this case.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is called `date`, even though it has a parameter it will conflict if you´re trying to call a variable the same name in this case `date`. What happens is that the compiler tries to use the declared constant `date` to assign its own initial value.

When you use `anythingButDate` then it´s fine because your function is not called that and you don´t have any other function called `anythingButDate`.

```
let date = date(from: "11:30") // will not work
let datex = date(from: "11:30") // will work
let anythingButDate = date(from: "11:30") // will work
```